# Navigation menu for a standalone WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf

Im just starting out with wpf (in blend 4) and i would like to create an application that has a side menu for changing the content. What i am looking for is something like in word 2010 under the file menu. if you click the menu on the left side the content on the right side changes accordingly. i have read articles about nesting a page.xaml into a frame and change the frames navigation source to each page. Is this right? When i do that a navigation bar appears at the top. I can get rid of that easy but it seems like i am taking the wrong path at what i want to achieve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The navigation bar you can get rid of by doing ShowsNavigationUI="False" in the page's XAML. I do believe you took the wrong project type, though - If you are working with pages, you're in a WPF _browser_ application. Normally, I associate standalone with a Windows application (WPF Application project type).

Comment: I am working with wpf application. The way i did it in vb forms was to hide/show form. So to change "pages" from say reports to overview i would just hide the reports contols and show the overview controls. Now im trying to do the same thing here where a button changes a part of the mainwindow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to chime in on this, both the `TabControl` and the `Frame`-based solutions are somewhat like the extremes of a spectrum. The tab control effects a very close coupling between the tab state and the displayed UI (e.g., you might find it difficult to change to a dialog for which there is no explicit tab item), whereas the frame enables relatively loose coupling, but might be overkill for this scenario, as it aims to support full-blown linear navigation with a history/page stack. (Prism, for example, offers a similar mechanism through its "regions" concept.)

A middle ground could be to have a main "window frame" UI with a placeholder element, and have your individual "pages" derive from `UserControl`, making them regular UI elements. To switch to a specific page in your UI, you would instantiate (through code or XAML resources) the corresponding user control, and set it as the `Content` property of the aforementioned placeholder element. (This is basically the same mechanism you mentioned for VB, where you hide/show subforms.)

So there's a range of options to choose from, depending on the actual constraints of your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest code to do that is creating a `TabControl` with `TabStripPlacement="Left"`. For example :

```
        <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left">
            <TabItem Header="Tab1" />
            <TabItem Header="Tab2" />
            <TabItem Header="Tab3" />
        </TabControl>
```

You can apply `Styles` to further change `UI`, colors and look & feel.